# VUE 3 JS : can't acces to my props in mounted

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, vue-props

I have a problem in a component.

I receive an id (name : theIdPost) from a parent file of this component but when I would like to use it in the mounted(){} part , it tells me :

> TS2339: Property 'theIdPost' does not exist on type '{...

I can print the id in template, no worries but to use it in the SCRIPT part it doesn't work.

the component file:

```js
<template lang="fr">

// All my html 

</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { store } from '../store/index';


export default{
  name: 'comment',
  props: {
    theIdPost: Number,
    theTxtPost: String, 
    theLike: Number,
  },
  setup() {
    const myStore: any = store

    const commentList = computed(() => myStore.state.commentList);
    console.log("CommentList > " +commentList.value);
    return { commentList };
  },
  mounted() {
    const myStore: any = store;
    myStore.dispatch("getComments", 
    {'id': this.theIdPost}
    );
  }

}


</script>
<style lang="scss">
@import "../scss/variables.scss";
// ..... the style part

</style>
```

Can you explain me why it doesn't work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Solution there is 2 points :

1. because I use vue 3 and setup in composition API , the lifecycle Hook is different and mounted => onMounted

```js
setup(props) {
  const myStore: any = store
  const commentList = computed(() => myStore.state.commentList);
   
  onMounted(() => {
    myStore.dispatch("getComments", 
      {'id': props.theIdPost}
    );
  })
   
  return { commentList };
},
```

2. when we use onMounted, is like when we use ref(),  we have to import before. So at the beginning of the SCRIPT part, we have to write :

```js
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
```

So my final script is :

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { computed, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { store } from '../store/index';


export default {
  name: 'comment',
  props: {
    theIdPost: Number,
    theTxtPost: String,
    theLike: Number,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const myStore: any = store;
    const commentList = computed(() => myStore.state.commentList);

    onMounted(() => {
      myStore.dispatch("getComments",
        { 'id': props.theIdPost }
      );
    })
    return { commentList };
  },
}

</script>
```

Thanks to Thomas for the beginning of the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the composition API with the `setup`, you have to add the lifecycle hooks differently:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html

```
setup(props) {
    const myStore: any = store

    const commentList = computed(() => myStore.state.commentList);
    console.log("CommentList > " +commentList.value);
    
    onMounted(() => {
        myStore.dispatch("getComments", 
            {'id': props.theIdPost}
        );
    })
    
    return { commentList };
  },
```

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I totally forgot this new point. But , now I have en other error : TS2304: Cannot find name 'onMounted'. . Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me too. i was setting up the setup and not pass props in to the setup. now okay

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30689179)